# C++ Передача нестатической функции обьекта класса в новый поток

Tags: c++, многопоточность, классы

Нужно передать нестатическую функцию обьекта класса в новый поток. Получился примерно такой синтаксис, но он не работает (выскакивает ошибка)

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        cout << 'A';
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    thread new_thread(a.Print); // ERROR

    new_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Суть ошибки понял, как ее решить - нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thread new_thread(&A::Print, a); // NO ERROR
```

Чтоб было понятней насчет передачи параметров, ну и вообще убедиться, что это работает :) - что-то типа

```
class A
{
public:
    string s;
    void Print(char z)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) cout << s << z;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a,b;
    a.s = "A";
    b.s = "B";
    thread x(&A::Print, a, '1'); // ERROR
    thread y(&A::Print, b, '2'); // ERROR

    x.join();
    y.join();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, на самом деле в гугле был такой ответ, но там говорилось, что нужно делать вот так ```thread x(&A::Print, "и сразу параметры"```. В результате это выдавало вполне логическую ошибку. Спасибо